# How to make this simple landing page flex box work in all relevant browsers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

For hours I have been trying to make a simple landing box banner layout work in all relevant browsers using flexbox, but without luck. In the following there is a sketch of the layout I want to realize. Basically just two boxes for an image and a title next to each other. Reaching a certain minimum width of the title box, the layout should wrap to a stacked layout:

[image: Simple two box layout for a landing page banner]

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="landing_page_box">
  <div class="landing_page_box_left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="landing_page_box_right">
    <figure>...</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
div.wp-block-columns.landing_page_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
}

div.landing_page_box_left {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.landing_page_box_right {
  flex: 2 0 66.66%;
}
```

While this seems to work in Firefox V70 and Chrome V78 there are Problems in Internet Explorer 11: The two boxes are always stacked, even if the browser window is big enough for the boxes placed to each other. Could you please help me with that issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would argue IE11 is not relevant and I think it’s supported by edge getting chromium and IE not

Comment: I agree, IE11 has very buggy flexbox support: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: use css media queries?

Comment: I've tested gman's solution and it works well. You need to use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in IE 11 and set `flex-direction` [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#Syntax) to `column-reverse` to make the title column at the bottom when wrap to a stacked layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here the left is set to size 1 and the right to size 2 so the left will be 33% size

If the window is 900px or less (so the left would be 300px) then switch to a column-reverse so it will be displayed as a column and the title will come last

```css
.landing_page_box {
  display: flex;
}
.landing_page_box_left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #cccccc;  
}
.landing_page_box_right {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .landing_page_box {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing_page_box">
  <div class="landing_page_box_left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="landing_page_box_right">
    <figure>...</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the same thing except set to 400px so you can more easily test live in a stack overflow snippet

```css
.landing_page_box {
  display: flex;
}
.landing_page_box_left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #ccc;  
}
.landing_page_box_right {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  background: #ddd;  
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .landing_page_box {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing_page_box">
  <div class="landing_page_box_left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="landing_page_box_right">
    <figure>...</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to auto-resize an image to fit a `<div>`, you can't apply an explicit `width` or `height` to the image tag. You could apply:

   ```
   max-width:100%;
   max-height:100%;
   ```

   And apply `overflow:hidden;` to the `<div>` to prevent the image overflowing.
2. I think your approach to center vertically is good enough.

You could check my sample below:

```css
.landing_page_box {
  display: flex;
}

.landing_page_box_left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.landing_page_box_right {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .landing_page_box {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing_page_box">
  <div class="landing_page_box_left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="landing_page_box_right">
    <figure><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF9SU.jpg"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once again thank you very much for your helpful answer! I upvoted your answers, but my votes aren't shown since I do not have enough posts yet...

Comment: @Stooky You're welcome. You could mark the most helpful suggestion as an answer if you have solved the issue. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions! Indeed, in this simplified example your approach works pretty well. However, if an image is added to the right column , you get some errors:

```
<figure><img src="..." sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"></figure>
```

- Firefox V70: The left title column is much smaller than 33%. To correct this, I changed "flex: 1 1 auto;" and "flex: 2 1 auto;" to "flex: 1 1 33.33%;" and "flex: 2 1 66.66%;", respectively.
- IE11: After the change above I tested the effect of adding an image to the right column in IE11. Sadly, the image  is too big and overflows significantly to the right side. Obviously, IE11 is not able to scale the image correctly to the width of the right column. Is there a workaround? Things get even worse if I shrink the browser window until the media query is triggered. Then, the whole flex box is messed up and overflown by the running text of the website. Don't get me wrong, I would love to ignore IE11. However, as far as I know the market share of this browser still is about 10%. Isn't that too large a number to be ignored?

Besides the errors, I want the title in the left column to be centered vertically, too. In my code I've already posted I realized this by adding the following lines to the respective css class:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

Although this works in all 3 browsers (even in IE11, yay!) I think that's more a workaround than a robust solution. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance for your answers!